# loop basd on over partition by id

Tags: sql-server, loops, while-loop

I have  a table like this

```
id  date    Label
1   01.01.2018  abc
1   02.01.2018  ade
1   31.12.2017  bde
1   03.01.2018  tm
2   02.02.2018  lkj
2   03.02.2018  dyj
2   05.02.2018  tm
2   04.02.2018  tm
3   02.01.2018  ui
3   04.02.2018  ght
3   03.02.2018  kiu
3   06.02.2018  hft
3   08.02.2018  ghu
3   01.12.2017  gfdt
```

I need to apply the logic like whenever the  label =tm grouped by id based on latest date,I need to get the row before  label =tm and if the label not equal tm grouped by id based on latest date
then retrieve the row based on the latest date

```
id  date            Label
1   01.01.2018      abc
**1 02.01.2018      ade**
1   31.12.17        bde
1   03.01.18        tm
2   02.02.2018      lkj
**2 03.02.2018      dyj**
2   05.02.2018      tm
2   04.02.2018      tm
3   02.01.2018      ui
3   04.02.2018      ght
3   03.02.2018      kiu
3   06.02.2018      hft
3   **08.02.2018    ghu**
3   01.12.2017      gfdt
```

My result table should look like

```
id  date        Label
1   02.01.2018  ade
2   03.02.2018  dyj
3   08.02.2018  ghu
```

do I need to apply loop in sql
I dont know how to apply loop basd on over partition by id
please hep me

Comment: Please fix your formatting.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what that middle paragraph is trying to say. Sorry. I realise there's a language barrier, but can you try to rephrase it? Split your definition into several sentences; one large sentence like that makes it very difficult to read or understand.

Comment: I want the previous row when label=tm based on the lastest date for each ids

Comment: Also, what data type are you storing your dates as? They look like their a `varchar`. This is a major problem. `'31.12.17' > '02.01.2018'` (Yes, that's right, I'm implying that 31 December 2017  is **AFTER** 02 January 2018).

Comment: yes you are right.now I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply remove rows where `Label = tm` and then search for max date for each ID

```
select
    id, date, label
from (
    select
        *, rn = row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc)
    from
        myTable
    where
        label <> 'tm'
) t
where
    rn = 1
```

Comment: Just added a comment on the question, but i think you might need to `CAST`/`CONVERT` the value of `date`. The fact that the OP has different formats for the value heavily implies that they aren't storing their dates as a `date`. if my hunch is correct, that'll mean that the ordering would be wrong.